# UK Transfer of Residence form - pet section

Tags: united-kingdom, pets

I'm moving to the UK in a couple weeks.  My family (including my dog) aren't coming for another couple months.  We're having our stuff shipped out 2 weeks before my family flies.

Filling out the ToR, the pet section asks if we're bringing a pet (we are).  It asks for the pet's "Pet Passport and Identification Details".  The UK doesn't accept Pet Passports from the US so we're not getting one.  We are going to get an EU Health Certificate but the pet has to travel within 10 days of getting the Certificate so we don't have one yet.

I don't know if we can wait until we have that info to fill out the form since our stuff is being shipped before the dog flies out.  Should I wait as long as I can?  Or just fill it out now and put in the dog's microchip number?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Maybe you could put in an answer for future users.

Comment: @mts Done.  Sorry about that.

Comment: great, thanks and +1 from me! No need to apologize either. Glad you managed to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting in my dog's microchip ID and it was accepted fine.  I did not wait to do the Health Cert.  My dog has been in the UK with me for over a month now so it worked out fine.